# Распознавание лиц на изображениях — как это работает?

Tags: распознавание-образов

Хочется быстро и относительно поверхностно въехать в тему распознавания графических образов: как даже простенькие фотоаппараты-мыльницы распознают лица/улыбки?

Что прочесть? — жажду ответов тех, кто написал в итоге своё распознавание чего-то.

Comment: Интересный вопрос.

 Особенно интересно есть ли у кого-нибудь из участников личный (практический) опыт программирования в этой области.

Comment: Записался на два бесплатных онлайн курса от Coursera, освещающих тему распознавания образов и обработки изображений:

 1. [Coding the Matrix: Linear Algebra through Computer Science Applications](https://www.coursera.org/course/matrix)
 2. [Image and video processing: From Mars to Hollywood with a stop at the hospital](https://www.coursera.org/course/images)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть классические алгоритмы. Все их и используют в той или иной форме. Начните читать с [Википедии](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86), а потом пару [ссылок](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148283/) с [хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133826/).